# my sql order by field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, field

```
SELECT id_emoticon, title, category 
FROM emoticons
WHERE id_emoticon IN (4, 4, 4, 4, 3) 
ORDER BY id_emoticon DESC
```

I'm having the query like this, and I get the result is only one 4 and one 3 ids. I need all the ids that I give inside the WHERE clause.

Any idea?

Comment: and what your's question? `PSYCHIC MODE ON`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a few moments to read the [FAQ], and take care to write a complete question carefully before hitting submit (to prevent downvotes and the like).  Please also take care to type the question accurately; the word `I` should be in upper case when it is the 1st person singular pronoun.

Comment: because you have only 1 record with 1 `4` and ` record with `ID` 3

Comment: but you are passing only `4s and  3` in your where clause

Comment: I need that duplicates also....

Comment: Your taste in formatting leaves much to be desired, but you've had people help you with it and you've undone their changes each time.

Comment: @RabNawaz this just example, if i give 4 four times means i need 4 result. but the where clause (where id_emoticons in(4, 4, 4, 4)) will give only one result, it's grouping results. i dont want to group my results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want order having  id_emoticon 4  followed by 3, in short descending order of id_emoticon

If this is the case use following

```
SELECT id_emoticon, title, category 
FROM fe_emoticons
WHERE id_emoticon IN (4, 4, 4, 4, 3) 
ORDER BY id_emoticon DESC
```

Comment: No i dont want the desc order, in this for Example : i'm having id 4 four times and id 3 one time, i need that full result.

Comment: @jahir: But how many records are there in your table with `id=4`?

Comment: no there are many of them, suppose i give 4 4times means it needs to return 4 times the id 4....

Comment: 'Tis puzzling; the original version of the question (in fact, the first 4 or 5 revisions of it) were in terms of an emoticons table.  Then it got changed to 'posts'.  It's hard to keep track of such changes!

Comment: @jahir: you suppose wrong.  There isn't even a particularly easy way to do what you're asking.  OTOH, saying the same thing 4 times doesn't make it any truer.